# How to change the login destination of a user in CentOS?

Tags: centos, webserver

I'm having a dedicated server hosted with RackSpace, what I need to know is how to change the login destination of my user when I'm getting logged in to my CentOS using the PUTTY.

When I'm getting logged in, what I see is `/home/<username>`

But what I need is `/var/www/html`

Comment: Define what you mean by "login destination", so please edit your question to improve it. Do you mean home directory? Then edit the `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: When I'm getting logged in, what I see is /home/<username>

What I need is /var/www/html

Comment: Please *edit your question*, don't comment it!

Comment: You should explain why you want some user's home directory become `/var/www/html/`; unless you know extremely well the caveats, I feel that you will open a huge security hole.... I strongly suggest to become more familiar with Linux before doing that....

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully [passwd(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) then edit (very carefully, as root) the `/etc/passwd` file. You may want to change the home directory of your user, i.e. change the 6<sup>th</sup> field of the line describing your user.

Alternatively, read much more about `ssh` and its configuration thru `$HOME/.ssh/config` and other files etc etc.. Very probably Putty is also configurable.

I am guessing that **you are *making a big mistake* in changing your user's home directory from `/home/youruser/` to `/var/www/html/`** but I leave the responsibility to you. You could also configure its login shell (on the remote Linux server) appropriately (e.g. thru `~/.login` where you could add a `cd /var/www/html` etc...)

Comment: "Very probably Putty is also configurable." I would like to go with this :) Any suggestion for the same.

Comment: I can't help. I never used Windows. But Putty being an adaptation of `ssh` is perhaps configurable in a similar way. Can't you take the appropriate time to RTFM ?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to modify the home directory for a user is to use `usermod`.

Using `usermod -d /var/www.html username` (as privileged user, i.e. root or using `sudo`) the home directory will be changed to the desired location.